# Basics of Google App Engine: get() method of handler

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am going through the Udacity web programming tutorial (https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs253/unit_2#submitting-input).

In Google App Engine, we have a file called main.py.

Here is the code for a very basic "main.py"

```
import webapp2

form = """
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(form)

 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                         debug=True)
```

I was looking through the webapp2 source (https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py) and saw that the get() method in the RequestHandler class isn't defined.

Where in the source code does it say that it's necessary to define the get(self) method of a handler? I understand I won't be able to understand all the details of GAE, but it would be nice to see where this is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* necessary to define the get method. It only necessary IF you want to serve HTTP GET Request.

Check this line which get a reference to the method correspond to http request
https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#555

And this line is calling it
https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#570

So if you have get method and there is a get request, the method on line 555 will point to the get function you defined, and line 570 will call it.